# Mimic ItemsControl behaviour in custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemssource

I have class Marker

```
class Marker {
  public double Position {get; set;}
  public string Label {get; set;}
}
```

and custom control that, among other properties, exposes collection of markers

```
class MyControl {
  public ObservableCollection<Marker> Markers {get; set;}
}
```

I'd like to mimic ItemsControl behaviour and allow users of my component to specify markers either directly or by using ItemsSource analogy. Moreover I'd like both methods to support databinding (preferably in XAML)

**Markers directly**

```
<my:MyControl>
  <my:MyControl.Markers>
    <my:Marker Position="{Binding X}" />
  </my:MyControl.Markers>
</my:MyControl>
```

**Marker using MarkersSource**

```
<my:MyControl MarkersSource={Binding UserSpecifiedCollection}">
</my:MyControl>
```

The first method is pretty straightforward but I'am struggling with the second one.

How  can I implement MarkesSource? How can be items of UserSpecifiedCollection converted to Marker type? How can be properties of UserSpecifiedCollection items be databound to properties of Marker?

Regards conversion I think a ValueConvertor can be used, but I would prefer pure XAML solution, something like DataTemplates. It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need dependency properties for bindings, you can "recycle" properties of other controls by using `DependencyProperty.AddOwner` or just create your own. Further you probably want to "forward" the binding from your property to the internal ItemsControl or whatever you use, e.g.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControls.MyUserControl3"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             Name="control">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Binds to the new property -->
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=MarkersSource}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
public partial class MyUserControl3 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MarkersSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MarkersSource",
                                        typeof(ObservableCollection<Employee>),
                                        typeof(MyUserControl3),
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> MarkersSource
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Employee>)GetValue(MarkersSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MarkersSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public MyUserControl3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
<uc:MyUserControl3 MarkersSource="{Binding DpData}">
    <uc:MyUserControl3.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type obj:Employee}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </uc:MyUserControl3.Resources>
</uc:MyUserControl3>
```

Here i implicitly apply a DataTemplate via resources, but you can just create another property (reuse ItemsControl.ItemTemplate) and forward that to the internal ItemsControl.

Comment: Syntax highlighting depends on the tags on the question.

Comment: @Rick Sladkey: So i have heard; it surely would be nice if it would be a bit more smart than that though...

Comment: It was an aha for me why it acted differently sometimes.

Comment: @Rick Sladkey: Yeah, i had a look around on meta when i noticed that it did not apply dynamically; Now i just retagged the question, the fact that there is c# code in the question itself should justify that :P